# json object working in Browsers but not in Android App

Tags: android, json, wordpress

I have begun working on using JSON to update the lists in my app. I have previously done this without much issue and understand the JSON objects fairly well. When I connect to http://chuckfranklinlaw.com/wp-json/posts/511 in my browser I get the JSON object as I would expect to see it, but when I attempt to connect to the JSON through my android app I get a json_missing_callback_param error message. Please note that this is my early code and the forcing of networking on the UI thread is for testing purposes only.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_events); //Was activity_postList
    //This was working before atempted modifications
    /*HTTPDownloadTask tester = new HTTPDownloadTask();
    String params = "http://www.chuckfranklinlaw.com/events/feed/";
    tester.execute(params);

    this.generateDummyData();*/

    JSONArray json = null;
    String str = "";
    HttpResponse response;
    HttpClient myClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost myConnection = new HttpPost("http://chuckfranklinlaw.com/wp-json/posts/511");

    TextView testText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testView);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

    try {
        response = myClient.execute(myConnection);
        str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
        testText.setText(str);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    str = str.replaceAll("\\<.*?>", "");

    try {
        json = new JSONArray(str);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I'm using the WP-JSON plugin and following its guidelines on how to format the URL. It also works in browsers.

Prior to any objects being created I had my log print out the string which I was receiving from the URL:

```
{"code":"json_missing_callback_param","message":"Missing parameter data"}
```

Here is the log when I attempt to use a JSONObject, for some reason it is passing me this error code instead of my objects, thats why I had intially set it up as an array.

> 05-08 13:06:49.378  10989-10989/com.chuckfranklin.chuckfranklinlaw W/System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: Value [{"code":"json_missing_callback_param","message":"Missing parameter data"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
>   05-08 13:06:49.378  10989-10989/com.chuckfranklin.chuckfranklinlaw W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
>   05-08 13:06:49.378  10989-10989/com.chuckfranklin.chuckfranklinlaw W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:160)
>   05-08 13:06:49.378  10989-10989/com.chuckfranklin.chuckfranklinlaw W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:173)
>   05-08 13:06:49.378  10989-10989/com.chuckfranklin.chuckfranklinlaw W/System.err﹕ at com.chuckfranklin.chuckfranklinlaw.Events.onCreate(Events.java:99)
>   05-08 13:06:49.378  10989-10989/com.chuckfranklin.chuckfranklinlaw W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6288)
>   05-08 13:06:49.378  10989-10989/com.chuckfranklin.chuckfranklinlaw W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
>   05-08 13:06:49.378  10989-10989/com.chuckfranklin.chuckfranklinlaw W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
>   05-08 13:06:49.378  10989-10989/com.chuckfranklin.chuckfranklinlaw W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
>   05-08 13:06:49.378  10989-10989/com.chuckfranklin.chuckfranklinlaw W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
>   05-08 13:06:49.378  10989-10989/com.chuckfranklin.chuckfranklinlaw W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
>   05-08 13:06:49.378  10989-10989/com.chuckfranklin.chuckfranklinlaw W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   05-08 13:06:49.378  10989-10989/com.chuckfranklin.chuckfranklinlaw W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>   05-08 13:06:49.378  10989-10989/com.chuckfranklin.chuckfranklinlaw W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
>   05-08 13:06:49.378  10989-10989/com.chuckfranklin.chuckfranklinlaw W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   05-08 13:06:49.378  10989-10989/com.chuckfranklin.chuckfranklinlaw W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>   05-08 13:06:49.378  10989-10989/com.chuckfranklin.chuckfranklinlaw W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
>   05-08 13:06:49.378  10989-10989/com.chuckfranklin.chuckfranklinlaw W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)

Comment: did you try to log the content of what you are receiving?

Comment: Your JSON is not a valid Array as you are trying to convert it to.  It would need to start with a bracket [.  Try converting it to a JsonObject.   I use POJO object based conversion frameworks like GSon or Jackson exclusively now.  Create POJOs of your json structure and it will convert it for you.

Comment: @njzk2 Yes, I am receiving {"code":"json_missing_callback_param","message":"Missing parameter data"}

Comment: @GaryBak That was an oversight on my part, but the string which I am receiving from my server is not the object that it should be. Printing it out on a log gives me the above object.

Comment: can't believe I didn't see that: you are using HttpPost when you are trying to do a GET.

Comment: @njzk2 That was the problem, its fixed and running! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Browsers and Android apps are two very different things. what you can do in a browser, you can not do in an android app.

Second of all,
The json from that [link](http://chuckfranklinlaw.com/wp-json/posts/511) is not a jsonArray. So you cannot do `json = new JSONArray(str)`. The json from that link is a pretty complex json object.

A snippet of that json

```
{
  "ID": 511,
  "title": "Test",
  "status": "publish",
  "type": "tribe_events",
  "author": {
       "ID": 1,
       "username": "AllenJames",
       "name": "Allen J.",
       "first_name": "Allen",
       "last_name": "James",
       "nickname": "Allen J.",
       "slug": "allenjames",
       "URL": "",
       "avatar": "http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/883cde1b0af767e5cd8eaeee192ed9fc?s=96",
       "description": "",
       "registered": "2015-03-01T19:47:22+00:00",
       "meta": {
              "links": 
                     {
                        "self": "http://www.chuckfranklinlaw.com/wp-json/users/1",
                        "archives": "http://www.chuckfranklinlaw.com/wp-json/users/1/posts"
                     }
               }
       },
       "content": "<p>This is the description of test event.</p>\n",
```

As a start, `JSONObject feed = new JSONObject(str);` would work. But you have to make a proper java class and fill that class with the data from this json to make it anything close to useful.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, unfortunately it doesn't help much with my problem. My issue is that I am not receiving that object from my URL as I would expect, instead it is passing me the array: [{"code":"json_missing_callback_param","message":"Missing parameter data"}] I had intially altered my code to array thinking I missed the brackets but I've fixed that, I still do not have the correct object coming through.

Comment: replace  
  
`HttpPost myConnection = new HttpPost("http://chuckfranklinlaw.com/wp-json/posts/511");`  
  
with  
  
`HttpGet myConnection = new HttpGet("http://chuckfranklinlaw.com/wp-json/posts/511");`